# Import a set of data sequentially from external file to every nth line of notepad++. any suggestions?

Tags: notepad++

I have answer Set like this kept in file1;
1.A
2.B
3.A
4.D
5.C

I want to import these answers at every 5th line of notepad++ file2. How to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to go:

- In file1, select the line you want to insert ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> )
- Then, in file2:

  - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
  - Find what: `(?:.+\R){5}\K`
  - Replace with: Paste the line copied above ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> )

    - in your example `1.A 2.B 3.A 4.D 5.C\n`  Notice the `\n` added at the end
  - *check Wrap around*
  - *check Regular expression*
  - *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
  - <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # start no capture group
    .+      # 1 or more any character but newline
    \R      # any kind of linebreak
){5}        # end group, must appear 5 times
\K          # for all we have seen until this position
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: I have not presented my question clearly. Let me correct this. I have n number of multiple choice questions in file 1 numbered serially from 1 to n. I have answer key for the questions in file 2 numbered serially from 1 to n. Now I want to put the nth answer of nth question say at 9th place (9th place from the start of line) of every 6th line. how to make it work?

Comment: @RajkumarJanarthanan: You can't do such thing with Notepad++, you have to write a script in your avorite scripting language. I suggest you to ask a new question (probably at https://stackoverflow.com) with all details, some lines of each input files and expected result.